# Updating values in the database using a dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've made an IT Support Ticketing System and I'm trying to change the value of `status` automatically after making a selection in the drop-down. Here's what it looks like :

[image: IT Support Ticketing System]

My concern is that whenever I make a selection, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```js
<table class="table">
     <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
      <th>Assignee</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Problem</th>
      <th>Status</th>
     </tr>
    <?php
     include ('database.php');
     $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM tickets order by ticketno DESC");
     $result ->execute();
     for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
    ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['time']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['priority']; ?></td>
      <?php if ($row_message['assignee']) : ?>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['assignee']; ?></td>
      <?php else : ?>
      <td>
       <form method="post" action="update1.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticketno" value="<?php echo $row_message['ticketno']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept"></input>
       </form>
      </td>
      <?php endif ; ?>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['subject']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['problem']; ?></td>
      <td>
       <label for=""></label> <select style="font-family: Questrial;" name="status" required>
        <option disabled selected hidden>Select Status</option>
        <option name="status" value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
        <option name="status" value="Closed: Cancelled">Closed: Cancelled</option>
        <option name="status" value="Closed: Solved">Closed: Solved</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Here's the script:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('option[name="status"]').click(function()
   {
     var status = $(this).val();
     $.ajax(
     {
     url:"update2.php", method:"POST",
     data:{status:status}, success: function(data)
     {
      $('#result').html(data);
     }
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
```

And here's update2.php

```js
<?php
//Insert Data
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $databasename = "companydb";
 
 try
 {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename",$username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
 if(isset($_POST["status"]))
 {
  $query = "INSERT INTO tickets(status) VALUES (:status)";
  $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
 array('status' => $_POST["status"])
 );
 
 $count = $statement->rowCount();
 if($count > 0)
 {
  echo "Data Inserted Successfully..!";
 }
  else
 {
  echo "Data Insertion Failed";
 }
 }
}

 catch(PDOException $error)
 {
  echo $error->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Here's my table schema:

[image: tickets table]

Comment: Have you checked that the ajax call works in the network tab (chrome dev tools)?

Comment: @jhnbrn Hmm I'm not sure if I know what you mean

Comment: Run your script while you have opened the dev-tools in google Chrome (see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Open the network tab and select XHR. Then you select an option from your dropdown and see if the ajax call has been made.